# Getting value of explode from php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Lets say i have a string delimited by ;

```
  $something = "dog;cat;horse;fish";
```

I know i can easily explode it and get the appropriate value from exploded array:

```
 $explode = explode(";",$something);
```

`$explode[1]` would be cat.

Is there a way i can do this inline in anyway?  by that i mean something like:

```
$favoritePet = explode(";",$something)[1];
```

`$favoritePet` would equal cat

Clearly the above is wrong, but I am hoping this illustrates what i am trying to get at, explode and get value at the same time.

Comment: While that is a feature of PHP 5.4+, think about how it affects your code readability.  To me, in a case like this an extra line of code adds to the readability.

Comment: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called array dereferencing and can be done in PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 0):

It is array dereferencing and I hope by doing

```
$favoritePet = explode(";",$something)[1];
```

it will return the 'cat' to $favoritePet variable in PHP 5.4+

In earlier versions of PHP you can do like this:

```
  echo current(explode(";",$something)); // get [0]
  echo next(explode(";",$something));    // get [1]
```

or you can write your own function to get it in one line, like below

```
  function GetValueAt($arr, $key = 0)
  {
     return $arr[$key];
  }
```

And call this function like

```
  echo GetValueAt(explode(';', $something));    // get [0]
  echo GetValueAt(explode(';', $something), 1); // get [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) change log. check out the third line, where it says:

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

Alternatively, you can create a trivial function that does the samething for you.

```
function r($array, $key){
  return (isset($array[$key])) ? $array[$key] : false; 
}
```

And get the result like this:

```
  $a = explode(...);
  echo r($a, 1)
```